# How to create new array from boolean object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I'm pretty sure that there is something similar, but I can't figure it out this one in my scope. I have an array, and I need to create another array based on an object (In this case, `BannerAtivo: true`).

**My JSON:**

```
[{
    "BannerID": 0,
    "BannerImage": "http://hotsite/example2.png",
    "BannerMin": "http://hotsite/example.png",
    "BannerTitulo": "Xurupita Style",
    "BannerDesc": "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Siamet",
    "BannerAtivo": false,
    "SetorId": 1
}, {
    "BannerID": 2,
    "BannerImage": "http://hotsite/example2.jpg",
    "BannerMin": "http://hotsite/example.jpg",
    "BannerTitulo": "Chihuahua",
    "BannerDesc": "Role",
    "BannerAtivo": true,
    "SetorId": 1
}]
```

I'm trying the following code:

```
var data = response.data;
$scope.banners = data;
var a = $scope.banners;
function check(a) {
    return a.BannerAtivo = true;
    console.log(BannerAtivo);
}
```

What I want is: Show it in my scope only the lists where in the object `BannerAtivo` is `true`. I have already tried filter, and couldn't figure out how to make it. I can't even show it on the console. I know this question is dumb, and yes, I'm pretty newbie in javascript and angular. Sorry.

Comment: You are doing an assignment with `= true` not a comparison. Use `== true` or `=== true`

Comment: @Fran I tried, but still, it doesn't show anything on the console. I'm pretty sure that I'm not getting the object right.

Comment: `$scope.banners = response.data.filter((banner) => banner.BannerAtivo);`

Comment: You `console.log(BannerAtivo)` doesn't execute, you are exiting the function before it with `return`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the JSON you posted ends up in `response`, then you need to run `filter()` on `response`, not `response.data`.

Here's working example code:

```js
var response = [{
  "BannerID": 0,
  "BannerImage": "http://hotsite/example2.png",
  "BannerMin": "http://hotsite/example.png",
  "BannerTitulo": "Xurupita Style",
  "BannerDesc": "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Siamet",
  "BannerAtivo": false,
  "SetorId": 1
}, {
  "BannerID": 2,
  "BannerImage": "http://hotsite/example2.jpg",
  "BannerMin": "http://hotsite/example.jpg",
  "BannerTitulo": "Chihuahua",
  "BannerDesc": "Role",
  "BannerAtivo": true,
  "SetorId": 1
}];

$scope = {};
$scope.banners = response.filter(banner => banner.BannerAtivo);
console.log($scope.banners);
```

Comment: Hey @Chris G Just tried your solution and it almost worked. Sums up that I really needed to use the data. So the only thing I changed was using response.data.filter(~~);
I'll give it to you the solution cuz it was the one that made me understand where I was making a mistake. Thanks for putting up the snippet, that really helped!

Answer (score 1):

You are actually assigning `true` to your variable in the `check` function instead of actually checking the value. Also, the `console.log` statement has no meaning after the `return` statement because it represents code that can never be reached.

Now to solve your problem, all you need to do is filter you array based on the boolean value as such :

```
$scope.banners = response.data.filter((value) => {
    return value.BannerAtivo;
});
```

Comment: I tried but I didn't really work. Tried to put the return in my console to check it and wasn't getting no response.
Harman's answer did the trick, but, just to learn a little bit more, how exactly this code should work? Btw, there is any better alternative to use this on Angular with directives?

Comment: I am not sure how Harman's solution worked and not this one. This solution is the short version of his solution. Maybe it did not work because your `response.data` is empty or not the right array you need. On the other hand, I do not think there is a better way of doing this, the `filter` is great for what you need.

Comment: Now I understood. Kinda slow learner but making progress (lmao). Your answer along with Chris snippet did the trick. Thanks for it!

Comment: Absolutely, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Run this code and check in console the returned array of objects with only true values.
Here you go:

```
    <html>
        <body>
             <script type="text/javascript">
             //Assuming you got response here
                 var data = [
                        {
                            "BannerID": 0,
                            "BannerImage": "http://hotsite/example2.png",
                            "BannerMin": "http://hotsite/example.png",
                            "BannerTitulo": "Xurupita Style",
                            "BannerDesc": "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Siamet",
                            "BannerAtivo": false,
                            "SetorId": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "BannerID": 2,
                            "BannerImage": "http://hotsite/example2.jpg",
                            "BannerMin": "http://hotsite/example.jpg",
                            "BannerTitulo": "Chihuahua",
                            "BannerDesc": "Role",
                            "BannerAtivo": true,
                            "SetorId": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "BannerID": 2,
                            "BannerImage": "http://hotsite/example2.jpg",
                            "BannerMin": "http://hotsite/example.jpg",
                            "BannerTitulo": "Chihuahua",
                            "BannerDesc": "Role",
                            "BannerAtivo": true,
                            "SetorId": 1
                        }
                    ];

                var returnTrueData = function () {
                var result = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { //looping through array of objects
                     for (key in data[i]) { //looping through each object

                          if(key === "BannerAtivo" && data[i][key] === true) { //If the key is "BannerAtivo" and it has value 'true'
                              result.push(data[i]); //push the whole object into the result array
                         }

                    }
                 }
                 console.dir(result);
                 return result;
              }


        returnTrueData();

    </script>
</body>
```

For your better understanding, see how to loop through objects or array of objects

Comment: That actually worked like a charm! Thank you! Really, thanks for spending your time with this to help me out!
Could I ask you about where I can "learn" a little bit more about those kind of searchs in arrays? I was looking for it on w3c and wasn't getting much.

Comment: All this is already done by [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: @AndréSousa you're welcome!
Please upvote and tick the answer if you think my effort was worth it :)
We are always here to help each other learn :)

Comment: @AndréSousa about the learning part, I learnt mostly while working out problems, you can work on some exercises on Objects and arrays. Learning by doing is best.

Comment: @Harman hello again! I just upvoted you (not sure who downvoted) but I'll give the answer to Chris because it is more suited to my code using angular. But for real, thanks again mate!

Comment: @AndréSousa makes sense giving the answer to chris :)